# Webdriver doesnt click on Google Search

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Its a very simple script, but I need help.

The webdriver clicks the google search button when there are no suggestions listed for the text typed (for eg macintosh). But when suggestions appear, how do I still make the webdriver click on the Google Search button.
My code below:

```
package newProj;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;


public class Google {


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {



    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");

    RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElementById("lst-ib").sendKeys("macintosh");

    WebElement gs = driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@value = 'Google Search']");

    gs.click();
    System.out.println("Search Done");

    driver.close();
}
```

}

but getting the below error. Pls help

> *Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 3288 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Jun 27, 2018 12:14:37 PM
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession INFO:
>   Detected dialect: OSS true Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element  is not clickable at point (598, 411).
>   Other element would receive the click: ...
>
>   (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.87)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.40.565498
>   (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds Build info:
>   version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time:
>   '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z' System info: host: 'HDC0007030', ip:
>   '10.50.90.19', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false,
>   applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false,
>   browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.40.565498
>   (ea082db3280dd6..., userDataDir: C:\Users\CSS116~1\AppData\L...},
>   cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts:
>   true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true,
>   locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
>   nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy:
>   normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false,
>   setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version:
>   67.0.3396.87, webStorageEnabled: true} Session ID: f4700c020ed7f67bd9e46a3c70fb4b02   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:276)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
>     at newProj.Google.main(Google.java:33)*

Answer (score 0):

driver.navigate().to("http:\google.com");

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[title='Search']")).sendKeys("sele");

    List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='sbsb_b']/li[*]"));

    Iterator<WebElement> itr=list.listIterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){

        WebElement element=itr.next();

        if(element.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("selenium webdriver")){

            element.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi...thanks for your input...I am actually not trying to click on any of the suggestions...taking your example, I want to type "sele" in the search box and then click on Google Search button (even when the suggestions are showing up). It works for me when there are no suggestion, but when suggestions show up, it doesnt click on the Google Search button.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tiny mistake. Replace `click()` by `submit()`, like below -

```
WebElement gs = driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@value = 'Google Search']");

gs.submit();
```

It will work.